# RenderPartial and ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, viewbag

I'm trying to modify this code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3
To make it to get the ViewBag data for render the View in the PDF.

Basically, I need to pass to Html.RenderPartial with a new Context my ViewBag, the code now is:

```
Html.RenderPartial(viewName, model);
```

And I'm trying to change it to something like:

```
Html.RenderPartial(viewName, model, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewBag));
```

I don't get any error but the Dictionary keeps empty.

BR

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try passing in the `ViewData` property instead of the `ViewBag`.

```
Html.RenderPartial(viewName, model, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData));
```

The `ViewBag` property is a dynamic object, so the `ViewDataDictionary` constructor you are calling is the one that takes a `object`.  You're better off to use the one that takes an already populated `ViewDataDictionary`.  The data in the ViewBag and ViewData are the same.

Comment: I can make it works, but I found also that I was using a variable named "ViewBag" I think that cannot be a great idea, so I changed it for a better name and I make this change and now works great!, thank you!

Comment: +1.Thank ! Great. I know about ViewData, but never used it. Some time stuck to this problem and most of time use to create a new viewModel to get out of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@Html.Partial(viewName)
```

In partial viewbag from main view will be accessible.

Ok. If you need render html from partial view to pdf you can use this code:

```
@{
    var htmlString = Html.Partial(viewName);    
    var pdfData = PdfComposerClass.CreatePdfStaticMethod(htmlString);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is not what I need, this is a special case, in some cases I need to render a view to a PDF, the api to do that works but is not getting the ViewBag data, I localize that Its create a new context, the problem seems in the line i wrote above.