# Partial parameters using both ViewData Dictionary and the ViewBag deletes ViewBag data

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, viewbag, viewdata

I need to pass some information to a partial cshtml view. I use a `ViewDataDictionary` and the `ViewBag` for that.

```
public ActionResult TaskPage(int ID = 0)
{
    ViewBag.breadcrumbs = new string[] {
        "List", "Tasks"
    };
    ViewBag.title = "Editing - My selected itemd";
    ViewBag.id = ID;
    return View();
}
```

and then when assembling the view I pass a `ViewDataDictionary` as well:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Components/_Header.cshtml", new ViewDataDictionary { { "role", "task-page" } })
```

My `_Header.cshmtl` file uses both this dictionary and the `ViewBag`.

```
  ViewBag.breadcrumbs = ViewBag.breadcrumbs != null ? ViewBag.breadcrumbs : new string[] { };
  var role = ViewData["role"];
```

To my surprise, the `ViewBag` does not contain any data when I pass the `ViewDataDictionary` as well. How is that possible? Any idea how to better handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "already in the ViewBag"?  ViewBag is only kept for the life of one request.  You can't put something in ViewBag, make a request, then expect it to be there in the next request.

Comment: The ViewBag is filled on the Controller. I added the specific code to clarify.

Comment: Looks like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729784/cant-access-viewbag-in-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok. How can I let other viewers know they can find the solution in this post since nobody posted an actual answer?

Comment: In fact, you can post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post [What's the difference between ViewData and ViewBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705426/whats-the-difference-between-viewdata-and-viewbag)

It would appear that "Internally ViewBag properties are stored as name/value pairs in the ViewData dictionary." which would suggest that you are overwriting the `ViewBag` when you pass a new `ViewDataDictionary` object

Taken from [this blog post](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Difference-Between-ViewBag-and-ViewData-in-MVC-3)

```
public dynamic ViewBag 
{ 
    get 
    { 
         if (_dynamicViewData == null) 
        {
            _dynamicViewData = 
            new DynamicViewDataDictionary(() => ViewData); 
        }
        return _dynamicViewData;
    }
}
```