# Passing data from Action Method returning "PartialView()" into the parent View | using ASP.NET Core MVC and jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, viewbag

This is my main view named `_ShowSingleProduct.cshtml`:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
            <!-- Review-->
            <div class="product-review pb-4 mb-4 border-bottom">
                 //*Here I'm going to load my comments*
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <button onclick="showMoreComments()" class="btn btn-outline-accent" type="button"><i class="ci-reload me-2"></i>بیشتر دیدن</button>
            </div>
</div>
```

I'm going to load my data(which are some comments from the users) inside a `<div>` with `class="product-review"` using `ajax`.

This is my Javascript code:

```
$(function() {
     ShowComment();
});

function ShowComment() {
      $(".product-review").load("/Products/_ShowComments/"+ @Model.ProductId);
};
```

Everything is ok now!

But I need to update my comments using ajax by every clicking on the `<button>` with

```
<button onclick="showMoreComments()" class="btn btn-outline-accent" type="button">
    <i class="ci-reload me-2"></i>بیشتر دیدن</button>
```

Here is the target action method which returns the partial view:

```
public IActionResult _ShowComments(int id, int take = 2, int pageId = 1)
{
    ViewBag.CurrnetPageId= pageId + 1;
    var comments = _productService.GetAllCommentsByProductId(id, take, pageId);
    return PartialView(comments);
}
```

My question is that how to take the value of `ViewBag.CurrnetPageId` to my parent view (_ShowSingleProduct.cshtml) because every time I need it, it returns me `null`; I tried the following way:

```
@{
     var currentPage=ViewBag.CurrnetPageId;
}

<script>
function showMoreComments() {
       var currentPageId =@currentPage;
       $(".product-review").load("/Products/_ShowComments?id=" + @Model.ProductId+"&pageId=" + currentPageId);
};
<script>
```

but still considering the `currentPageId` variable as `null`!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Child actions follow a different controller/model/view lifecycle than parent actions. As a result they do not share ViewData/ViewBag.

**You can try this method.**

```
public IActionResult _ShowComments(int id, int take = 2, int pageId = 1)
{
    ViewBag.CurrnetPageId= pageId + 1;
    var comments = _productService.GetAllCommentsByProductId(id, take, pageId);
    return PartialView(comments);
}
```

In your Partial View (`Products/_ShowComments`) , use `@ViewBag.CurrnetPageId` to receive the data

```
//........

// add this code to save the data
<input id="currentPageId" value=@ViewBag.CurrnetPageId type="hidden"/>
//......
```

Finally, When load the partial view in parent view, Use `$("#currentPageId").val()` to get the value of `@ViewBag.CurrnetPageId`

```
<script>
function showMoreComments() {
   $(".product-review").load("/Products/_ShowComments?id=" + @Model.ProductId +"&pageId=" + $("#currentPageId").val());
}
<script>
```